# Vision transformer model not training as it should

Tags: python, pytorch, transformer-model, vision, torchvision

Here is the code for the vision transformer that I built using Pytorch. The model shows a cross entropy of 2.31 and an accuracy of around 10%. This remains the same across all the epochs. Hence, the model is unable to train. Please let me know what I am doing wrong, and if possible, please send a revised code. Thanks in advance!

PS: The model is trained on MNIST

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Jul  2 14:04:19 2023

@author: Paras
"""

import torch
from torch import nn
from torchvision import transforms
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np
import math

class Head(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,num_heads,weight_dimension):
        super(Head, self).__init__()
        self.w1 = nn.Parameter(torch.randn((weight_dimension*num_heads,weight_dimension))).to(device)
        self.w2 = nn.Parameter(torch.randn((weight_dimension*num_heads,weight_dimension))).to(device)
        self.w3 = nn.Parameter(torch.randn((weight_dimension*num_heads,weight_dimension))).to(device)
        
        
    def forward(self,x):
        
        x = x.to(device)
        self.Q = torch.matmul(x,self.w1).to(device)
        self.K = torch.matmul(x,self.w2).to(device)
        self.V = torch.matmul(x,self.w3).to(device)
        
        lnq = nn.LayerNorm(self.Q.size()[1:]).to(device)
        lnk = nn.LayerNorm(self.K.size()[1:]).to(device)
        lnv = nn.LayerNorm(self.V.size()[1:]).to(device)

        self.Q = lnq(self.Q)
        self.K = lnk(self.K)
        self.V = lnv(self.V)
        self.K = torch.transpose(self.K, -2, -1)

        out = torch.matmul(self.Q,self.K)
        out = out/np.sqrt(self.Q.shape[1])
        out = F.softmax(out,dim=-1)
        out = torch.matmul(out,self.V)
        return out
        
    
class MHA(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,num_heads,weight_dimension):
        super(MHA, self).__init__()
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.weight_dimension = weight_dimension
        heads = []
        for i in range(self.num_heads):
            head = Head(self.num_heads,self.weight_dimension)
            heads.append(head)
            
        self.heads = heads
        
    def forward(self,x):
        
        flag=True
        for i in range(self.num_heads):
            if flag:
                out_multihead = self.heads[i](x)
                flag=False
            else:
                out_multihead = torch.cat((out_multihead,self.heads[i](x)),axis=2)
        
        return out_multihead
            
    
class vit_model(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,img_size,patch_size,embedding_dim,n_heads,hidden_dims_mlp,n_classes,batch_size):
        
        super().__init__()
        self.patch_size = patch_size
        self.n_heads = n_heads
        self.hidden_dims_mlp = hidden_dims_mlp
        self.img_size = img_size
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        self.embedding_dim = embedding_dim
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        
        embedding_rows = self.patch_size*self.patch_size
        embedding_cols = self.embedding_dim
        embedding_cols = int(embedding_cols)
        
        self.embedding_matrix = nn.Parameter(torch.randn((embedding_rows,embedding_cols)))
        self.embedding_matrix.requires_grad_(True)
        
        self.added_class_head = nn.Parameter(torch.randn((1,embedding_cols))) #Normally distributed like nn.init.normal_ (std 10-6)
        self.added_class_head.requires_grad_(True)
        
        self.positional_embeddings = nn.Parameter(self.get_positional_encodings((img_size//patch_size)**2,embedding_cols)) #Trunc Normal distribution
        self.positional_embeddings.requires_grad_(True)
        
        self.weight_dimension = embedding_cols//self.n_heads
        
        self.mha = MHA(self.n_heads,self.weight_dimension)
        
        self.mlp_inside_encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.embedding_dim*(self.positional_embeddings.shape[0]+1), self.hidden_dims_mlp),
            nn.GELU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.5),
            nn.Linear(self.hidden_dims_mlp, self.embedding_dim*(self.positional_embeddings.shape[0]+1)),
            nn.GELU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.5)
            )
        
        self.mlp_classification = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.embedding_dim, self.n_classes),
            nn.GELU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.5),
            nn.Linear(self.n_classes, self.n_classes),
            nn.GELU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.5)
            )
        
    def divide_image_into_patches(self,imgs,patch_size):
        
        imgs = imgs/255
        
        startx, starty = 0,0
        batch_size, channels, height, width = imgs.shape
        
        flag = True
        for startx in range(0,height,patch_size):
            for starty in range(0,width,patch_size):
                tmat = imgs[:,:,startx:startx+patch_size,starty:starty+patch_size]
                
                tmat = tmat.reshape((batch_size,1,tmat.shape[1]*tmat.shape[2]*tmat.shape[3]))
                if flag:
                    patches_list = tmat
                    flag=False
                else:
                    patches_list = torch.cat((patches_list,tmat),1)

        return patches_list
    

    def get_positional_encodings(self,seq_length, hidden_size):
        position = torch.arange(seq_length).unsqueeze(1)
        div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0, hidden_size, 2) * (-math.log(10000.0) / hidden_size))
        encodings = torch.zeros(seq_length, hidden_size)
        encodings[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(position * div_term)
        encodings[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(position * div_term)
        return encodings
    
    
    def forward(self,images):
        
    
        out = self.divide_image_into_patches(images,self.patch_size)
        out = torch.matmul(out,self.embedding_matrix)
        out = out + self.positional_embeddings.unsqueeze(0).expand(self.batch_size, -1, -1)
        out = torch.cat((out,self.added_class_head.expand(self.batch_size, 1, -1)),1)
        out = out.to(self.device)
        ln = nn.LayerNorm(out.size()[1:]).to(self.device)
        out = ln(out)
        layer_norm1 = out.clone()
        out = self.mha(out)
        out = out + layer_norm1
        skip = out.clone()
        out = out.to(self.device)
        ln = nn.LayerNorm(out.size()[1:]).to(self.device)
        out = ln(out)
        out = self.mlp_inside_encoder(out.reshape(out.shape[0],out.shape[1]*out.shape[2]))
        out = skip + out.reshape(self.batch_size,layer_norm1.shape[1],self.embedding_dim)
        out = out[:,-1,:]
        out = self.mlp_classification(out)
        return out

# Define the transform to normalize the data
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))])

# Load the training and test datasets
train_dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=True, transform=transform)
test_dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=False, transform=transform)

# Create data loaders
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, shuffle=True, batch_size=1000)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset, shuffle=False, batch_size=1000)

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)
model = vit_model(28, 4, 512, 8, 2048, 10, 1000)
model = model.to(device)
print(model)
#num_params = sum(p.numel() for p in model.named_parameters())
for p in model.named_parameters():
    print(p)
#print('Number of parameters:',num_params)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)


epoch_losses = []
epoch_accuracies = []
for epoch in range(100):  # Number of training epochs

    epoch_loss = []
    epoch_acc = []
    model.train()
    for i, (images,labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        images = images.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)
        c = model(images)
        loss = criterion(c,labels)

        with torch.no_grad():
            predictions = torch.argmax(c, dim=-1)

        acc = torch.sum(predictions == labels)/1000
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        epoch_loss.append(loss.item())
        epoch_acc.append(acc.cpu().numpy())

    model.eval()
    epoch_losses.append(np.average(epoch_loss))
    epoch_accuracies.append(np.average(epoch_acc))
    print('Epoch loss:',epoch_losses[-1])
    print('Epoch accuracy:',epoch_accuracies[-1])
```

I tried varying learning rates, patch sizes, etc. hyperparameters, but it did not work.

Comment: For classification, your model should have a output softmax activation.

Comment: Additionally to Dr. Snoopy's diagnosis, I would like to add that your learning rate is pretty aggressive, and SGD is usually not the best learning scheme.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy you are not correct, he is using nn.CrossEntropyLoss which requires inputs as unnormalized logits, i.e. no softmax.

Comment: @RadekSvoboda Sure, now you should then provide alternate explanation on why the model does not train, and softmax has to be applied at some point anyway (to get predictions).